# CMake import local shared library and how to include it in a header

Tags: c++, import, cmake, shared-libraries

I'm stuck to import a shared library in another project with CMake.

**my-utils-lib**

My lib files are generated in my-utils-lib project:

*CMakeLists.txt*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(my-utils-lib VERSION 1.0.0 DESCRIPTION "Utils for C++.")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_library(
    my-utils-lib SHARED
        ./src/string_utils/find_matches.cpp
        ./src/string_utils/split.cpp
        ./src/string_utils/format.cpp
        ./src/vector_utils/print_vector.cpp
)

set_target_properties(
    my-utils-lib PROPERTIES
        VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
        SOVERSION 1
)

target_include_directories(my-utils-lib PRIVATE src)

include(GNUInstallDirs)

install(
    TARGETS my-utils-lib
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
        EXPORT my-utils-lib
)

configure_file(my-utils-lib.pc.in my-utils-lib.pc @ONLY)

install(
    FILES ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/my-utils-lib.pc 
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR}/pkgconfig
)
```

I run `mkdir build && cd ./build/ && cmake .. && sudo make install` to generate and install my library files.

Finally, my-utils-lib project tree looks like this:

```
CMakeLists.txt
my-utils-lib.pc.in
src/
  |_main.cpp
  |_main.h
  |_string_utils/
    |_find_matches.cpp
    |_find_matches.h
    |_format.cpp
    |_format.h
    |_split.cpp
    |_split.h
  |_vector_utils/
    |_print_vector.cpp
    |_print_vector.h
```

**my-project**

In another project, I'd like to import "split.h" in one of my local headers without having to enter the full path to the actual file. Something like:

```cpp
#include "my-utils-lib/string_utils/split.h"
```

I tried many solution so far, none of them is working. My last attempt is:

*CMakeLists.txt*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(longer_sub_sequence)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_library(my-utils-lib libmy-utils-lib.1.0.0.dylib)
add_library(my-utils-lib SHARED IMPORTED)

add_executable(
    longer_sub_sequence
        main.cpp
        visualization/draw_matrix.cpp
        visualization/draw_matrix.h
)

target_link_libraries(longer_sub_sequence my-utils-lib Qt5::Widgets)
```

CMake autobuild runs fine (I am using CLion as an IDE) but I can't find how to import any code from my library.

I checked in /usr/local/lib (where CMake generated my lib files), and found the correct lib files :

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*my-utils-lib*" -print

./libmy-utils-lib.1.0.0.dylib
./libmy-utils-lib.1.dylib
./libmy-utils-lib.dylib
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: If you want to use your library project via `find_package(my-utils-lib)`, then you need to add `install(EXPORT)` and some other commands to its `CMakeLists.txt` (see more detailed example in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/manual/cmake-packages.7.html)). The fie `my-utils-lib.pc` is used by `pkg-config` utility; in CMake it is used with help of [PkgConfig](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/module/FindPkgConfig.html) module.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I completly changed my configuration to export my library as a well configured package. I was able to run CMake successfully (my-utils-lib was found by find_package, yay! I also noticed find_library still runs fine even when lib doesn't exist, unlike find_package). But... I'm still stuck at the very same startpoint : I cannot find a way to use my library inside any of my project files, none of `#include "my-utils-lib/string_utils/split.h"` or `#include <my-utils-lib/string_utils/split>` works

Comment: Please, update the question to reflect the changes you have made.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to install the library header.
You should add an `install` command for header just like you did with the library binary.

Moreover you should consider using comparison signs (`<` and `>`) instead of double quote for include directive :

```
#include <my-utils-lib/string_utils/split.h>
```

One last remark, you are generating and installing a `.pc` file which is used by pkg-config only and you're not using it.